# How can I simulate an blocking function using Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads. One is the customer and the other is the productor.

I want to call a function in the the customer called READ. That should block indefinitely until the producer put data on it.

How can I do it ?
Thanks !

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Using synchronization blocks, but was busy waiting

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you to use `LinkedBlockingQueue`. It's the easiest method to simulate 'producer-consument' problem. One thread puts values to the queue using `put` method and the other consumes data using `take` which is blocking (thread waits until the queue is not empty). Using `LinkedBlockingQueue` is very easy because you don't have to synchronize your methods. Everything is already done.

Comment: Yea ... no need to reinvent wheels.  (Especially square ones that use busy waiting.)

Comment: Actually, I think any `BlockingQueue` would do wouldn't it?

Comment: Overkill for this.  You could use ReentrantLock or a Sempahore, both of which are much simpler approaches and will make more sense to someone reading the code.

Comment: Its a good idea,didn't know about this class, thank you ! But I aiming embedded devices with 1.3 support only

Answer (score 2):

if the data to be put in the queue requires synchronization i.e. producer produces one object and stores it in a queue; consumer must take consume the object put by the producer, using SynchronousQueue or new TransferQueue should be a better idea

Answer (score -3):

Use `thread.wait()` and then `thread.notify()`. `thread.wait()` waits until the `thread.notify()` happens.

Comment: notify or notifyAll? How about monitors? etc. That's very low level and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: -1 - And if the `notify` happens first the whole process fails. When will people stop recommending archaic and broken solutions to already solved problems!!!